# NSUrl request does not work in a Xamarin Today Widget

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, nsurl

hey Guys I am working on a Today Widget in Xamarin using C# that open's a certain app that is installed on the iPhone. I'm using NSUrl request to do this however when I run the widget and click on a button it says unable to load

here's my code:

```
 using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using UIKit;
using NotificationCenter;

namespace ToolBelt
{
    partial class ToolBeltView : UIViewController
    {
        public ToolBeltView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }
        public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

            var controller = NCWidgetController.GetWidgetController ();
            controller.SetHasContent(true, "com.d4a.toolbelt.Widget");
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            webbutton.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                NSUrl request = new NSUrl ("http://www.google.com");

                try {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (request);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Cannot open url: {0}, Error: {1}", request.AbsoluteString, ex.Message);
                    var alertView = new UIAlertView ("Error", ex.Message, null, "OK", null);

                    alertView.Show ();
                }
            };

            emailbutton.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                NSUrl request = new NSUrl ("mailto:");

                try {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (request);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Cannot open url: {0}, Error: {1}", request.AbsoluteString, ex.Message);
                    var alertView = new UIAlertView ("Error", ex.Message, null, "OK", null);

                    alertView.Show ();
                }
            };

            musicbutton.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                NSUrl request = new NSUrl ("music://");

                try {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (request);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Cannot open url: {0}, Error: {1}", request.AbsoluteString, ex.Message);
                    var alertView = new UIAlertView ("Error", ex.Message, null, "OK", null);

                    alertView.Show ();
                }
            };


            itunesbutton.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                NSUrl request = new NSUrl ("http://itunes.apple.com/genre/music/id36?mt=8");

                try {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (request);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Cannot open url: {0}, Error: {1}", request.AbsoluteString, ex.Message);
                    var alertView = new UIAlertView ("Error", ex.Message, null, "OK", null);

                    alertView.Show ();
                }
            };


            appstorebutton.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                NSUrl request = new NSUrl ("http://itunes.apple.com/genre/mobile-software-applications/id36?mt=8");

                try {
                    UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl (request);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Cannot open url: {0}, Error: {1}", request.AbsoluteString, ex.Message);
                    var alertView = new UIAlertView ("Error", ex.Message, null, "OK", null);

                    alertView.Show ();
                }
            };

        }

    }

}
```

i'm new to Xamarin Development so any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extensions have their own way of opening URLs (since the device could be locked when opening a URL on an extension), so you need to use the ExtensionContext

`ExtensionContext.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("yoururl://"), null);`

Comment: Thank you for the reply! do I replace the whole NSURL with the snippet that you gave me or do I add it somewhere? Please let me know and thank you a million times over!

Comment: I tried that and I looks like its trying to open it within the widget any ideas on how to fix that? Please let me know.

Comment: I would just double check the Today extension is set up correctly, you can take a look at an example here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_extensions/ - but that's 100% the method you would need to use.

Comment: So I looked into the link you sent me and after doing more research I found out that the ExtensionContext.OpenUrl(new NSUrl("yoururl://"), null); tries to open the url within the widget not in said app how would I make it to where when the user clicks the webbutton it open google.com in safari? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Works fine for me, closes the Today notification view, opens up Safari and goes to the entered page. If you make a small sample app that doesn't work, I'll happily take a look into it.

Comment: wow that's crazy i'm still not able to get it to work I added a sample project to github would you mind looking at it for me? here's the link: https://github.com/TeamBrainStorm/Xamarin-Today-Widget Thank you for all your help! :)

Comment: UPDATE: I just noticed I had a Xamrain Studio Update on my mac I updated it and made it from scratch again and your code works perfectly! Thank you for all your help your AWESOME! :)